# Code runs different on USB vs Battery

Tags: arduino-uno, display

I have two Arduino, one is to handle the Bluetooth communication and send a signal to the other Arduino, and the other to interpret the signal and display or hide an image on the E-ink display.

It work just fine when they both are connected through the USB. But when I connect a 9V battery to the Arduino running the E-ink, instead of the USB, the image is displayed and cleared (looping), as if the IF ELSE conditions are not there.

I have tested if it actually runs the method by adding delay to the showImg()-method, and that seems to work.

I have also tested with connecting the USB cable to the E-ink Arduino to a 5V charger, and the case is the same.

Image:
[image: Setup]

Bluetooth code:

```
int ledPin = 13; 
int state = 0;
int flag = 0; 

void setup() {
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

 if(Serial.available() > 0){
 state = Serial.read();
 flag=0;
 }

 if (state == '2') {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 if(flag == 0){
 Serial.println("Screen: off");
 flag = 1;
 }
 }

 else if (state == '1') {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
 if(flag == 0){
 Serial.println("Screen: on");
 flag = 1;
 }
 }
}
```

E-ink code:

```
#include <epd.h>

int displayed = 0;
int val = 0;

void showImg(void)
{
  Serial.print("showImg");
  displayed = 1;
  //epd_clear();
  epd_disp_bitmap("PIC9.bmp", 0, 100);

  epd_udpate();
  //delay(10000);
}

void clearImg(void){
  Serial.print("clearImg");
  displayed = 0;
  epd_clear();
  epd_udpate();

}

void setup(void)
{
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  epd_init();
  epd_wakeup();
  epd_set_memory(MEM_TF);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);

}

void loop(void)
{
  val = digitalRead(7);

  if(val == 1){

    if(displayed == 0){
      showImg();
    }

  }else {

    if(displayed == 1){
      clearImg();
    }
  }
  //Serial.println(val);
  //delay(3000);
}
```

I am a beginner when it comes to Arduino, So I hope someone can give me some hints to what may be wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to fix the following ambiguity: in “connecting ... to a 5V charger ... the case is the same” it isn't clear whether you mean like the battery setup or like the USB-to-computer setup, ie, whether it fails or works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB provides the one thing that is missing from your diagram there: the **common ground**.

The GND pins of the two boards *must* be connected together. By using USB the USB becomes that connection. As soon as you use batteries there is no connection, so no communication happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Majenko. You are absolutely right, and I'm surprised I did not see this.... Thank you!